# UITableview With Large Header Image

Tags: uitableview

I want my app to have a large header like the living social app: [image: http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/076/Purple/7c/63/f8/mzl.badtvvxi.320x480-75.jpg]

I tried doing this by hiding the navbar on the main delegate and just making a UIImageView to hold the pic, but the transition to the detail view looked funky.  How can I get a custom image at the top of my tableview?  Maybe I did something funky and need to try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YournavigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
```

And on top of that, this site has a good tutorial on how to add a background image to the UINavigationBar, these two things together should give you just what you're looking for!

http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

Should to the trick!

Comment: This is great. Now, when I load the detail view, there is no back button...why is this?